# How do i create nice looking controls?

Tags: vb.net, controls, tabcontrol, groupbox

I found a nice controls used by a software so wanted to use or build similar nice looking controls for my applications in vb.net

First Sample control is nice rounded cornor group box [ i guess so ]:
http://sachicomputer.com/kabin/samples/control1.jpg

and second control is nice looking tab control:

[http://sachicomputer.com/kabin/samples/control1.jpg](http://sachicomputer.com/kabin/samples/control2.jpg)

Edited:

Yeah I tried enablevisualstyles but it didn't show any difference. Do i need to run other commands in conjucation with it? I found my program still displaying same old look but other one application showing office 2007 look. So how can it be done?

I am testing it in windows 2003 server.

Comment: This is a complex question that covers coding and design skills.  There are some nice, free control libraries out there.  I use the free version of www.componentfactory.com for pet projects and have the paid version at work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to do quite a bit of drawing by yourself. This MSDN section deals with [Custom Control Painting and Rendering](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxys6ytf%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) and the documentation for [Control.Region](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.region.aspx) has a sample for making round buttons that you might be able to adapt.

I'd suggest having a look at the [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/) site as well, a lot of people have written articles there about customizing various controls